Is it ok to ask for different proof of a proof?
I have a problem that I have proven with elementary tools. I am wondering if I can ask for possible non-elementary proofs in mathematics exchange? This would help me in understanding which branches of mathematics might be related to my problem that I'm unaware of?

You want a “proof of a proof”? Now that’s what I call meta, +1!

this is an excellent way to learn! A lot of areas can seem abstract or impenetrable but when you have a concrete problem in hand whose solution/behavior is already understood to you and you then re-phrase that using the the new area suddenly things become very clear.

It's probably OK. I do have two pointers that should improve your chances that your question is well-received:

Try to be as clear as possible about what you're looking for. What, to you, is an "elementary tool/proof"? It doesn't have to be mathematically, formally precise, but the less ambiguity the better. List some tools you consider to be elementary. If you have heard of some less elementary tools that you think could help, list them as well. Make sure you include at least one of the proofs you've come up with in the question both for the sake of demonstrating an elementary proof, as well as providing evidence that you have thought about the problem yourself.

I wouldn't exclude alternative elementary proofs from the question. You can state that you'd like to see some more exotic proofs, but to build in a "non-elementary" requirement adds a somewhat opinion-based restriction on answerers, and risks the question being closed for being opinion-based.

Use the alternative-proof tag, but don't just use this tag. Use appropriate tags to indicate roughly which branch of mathematics your question lies in. If you have good reason to believe that your question could be answered by experts in a different field, you could consider including an appropriate tag from that field... but do not go overboard. If the theorem is particularly well-known and well-studied, the tag big-list may also be appropriate.


Basically, keep it as focused and as unambiguous as possible. Try, as much as possible, to avoid prospective answerers having to guess what you mean. This is is more difficult with a question like this, but with a little care, it should be received well enough.
... (unless it's a duplicate).

A good set of suggestions for avoiding many a pitfall. Don't know if it is comprehensive, but that's not really the point. Well done!

+1 for the suggestion to clarify what elementary means. To some people, it means "not involving complex numbers".
